# How to properly call dependency classes (Class not found)

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

I'm creating a custom module that uses PHPMailer, which has been installed in the module's vendor folder via composer.

This is the error I get:

`Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in Drupal\multisend\Service\MailerService->__construct()`

PHPMailer is being used in a service class and a PHPMailer object is being created in the service classes constructor. Here is the code:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\multisend\Service;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


class MailerService
{
    private $mailer;
    private $config;
    private $attorney_data;

    public function __construct($attorney_data)
    {
        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer(true);
        $this->config = \Drupal::config('multisend.settings');
        $this->attorney_data = $attorney_data;
    }

    ...
```

I've even tried `require()` on the PHPMailer class but no luck. If anyone could give any suggestions, I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Are those the right paths for the `use` statement? Also, strive to use dependency injection for your classes (no `new` statement or global container). `require` should never be needed in 99% of cases. How did you install the package? It states that it’s in the modules vendor folder, but it should really be in the root vendor folder.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, I initially installed the package into the module's directory but found that the only time my code would work is if I used a Drupal namespace. So... I added it to the root vendor folder and tried the dependency injection approach but still nothing. What is proper protocol when using a package in a Drupal module?

Comment: sooo ... `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer` installs the package in the root vendor folder like @keven ^^ says  should just be 
"use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer" if not perhas "use phpmailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer" ??!

Comment: External packages have their own namespaces, using Drupal on them won’t work. I suggest using an IDE like PHPStorm, it will reduce the guessing on namespaces and paths and dependency injection.

Comment: The namespace that I'm using is the only one that PHPStorm suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is right the onlything is never try to `composer require X` in a modules directory even though you can include a composer.json file in the module its self 
always make sure you are in the site root. then the paths will be correct.

Comment: But then how does one install a module without having to install each dependency manually in the root director if a module does not include its dependencies?

Comment: Simple. look at https://www.drupal.org/project/address as an example 
If you download it and open the folder you will see it includes a composer.json file, in the module  which defines the  'dependencies' so when you run "composer require 'drupal/address:^1.4'" from the root folder it (composer/drupal) checks for module dependencies and installs them automatically ... see 

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies

but because you are making your own module , you must first add dependencies manually

Comment: The dependencies are listed in the .info file of the module a d composer.json of that module - but you don’t run composer install from the modules directory. You have to require your dependencies at the root.